# How can get a queryset and for each object get it queryset

Tags: python, django

for example I have these models :

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    .....


class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .....
```

Now if I want get a values of teachers I can do it with : `Teacher.objects.values("id", "name")` but how can I add a queryset of students to the teachers queryset values?

here is the expected output as JSON :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alan",
  "students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "...": "...",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Sam",
      "...": "...",
    },
    {....},
    {....},
  ]
}
```

Note : I know I can do it by getting students queryset , but in this case I will have many duplicated teachers , so I just want each teacher and his students as array of objects

Answer (score 0):

`Sudent` objects are accessible from `Teacher` as `Teacher.objects.student_set`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward.

If you add `related_name="students"` to `Student.teacher` model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="students")
```

then you can use `Teacher.objects.students`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name.

And BTW, are you sure about `on_delete=models.CASCADE`?

Comment: Update the question .. i'm not sure this will solve my problem , and what do you mean about `on_delete` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer probably, but you could use `Serializer` or `ModelSerializer` of `django-restframework` to serialize your models to `json`.